# Drupal Recruiter issue with setup

Tags: php, drupal

I am very new to using this `recruiter module` on `drupal` and hence i decided to ask some few questions here.
I have recently downloaded this `drupal` Recruiter module, setting it up is where i have few challenges as i have never done this before, hence i have to ask here.

How do i go about setting it up. Like inside my Control Panel do i have to extract it and set it up from there using the database configuration details or? Please I do need some form of clarification here.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways for installing drupal modules:

- You can download module's archive, unpack it and upload module dir to (most common place) `sites/all/modules`. Then go to modules admin page and enable the module.
- If you have `drush` installed you can use it to download, install and activate the module
- If you have FTP access for your site you can install new module from Drupal's back-end. You just have to provide path to module archive. For example: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/name.tar.gz